# If I know Java, what do I need to know to connect an Android application to a SQLite database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to learn how to program databases for Android and to my knowledge that is SQLite. If I know Java what else do I need to learn so that I can build a database? Any other information that you could help me with would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need a DatabaseHelper class, example of DataBaseHelper.class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private String sql;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

//database name
private static final String NAME_DB = "Courses.sql";    

//database version
private static final int VERSION_DB = 1;

//database table name
public static final String COURSES_TABLE = "courses";

//database table columns for N_TABLE
public static final String ID_KEYROW= "_id";
public static final String ID_COURSE= "courseid";
public static final String ID_TITLE = "title";
public static final String ID_INSTRUCTOR = "instructor";
public static final String ID_LENGTH = "length";
public static final String ID_RATING = "rating";
public static final String ID_TOPIC = "topic";
public static final String ID_SUBJECT = "subject";
public static final String ID_DESCRIPTION = "description";  
//private final Context myContext;

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, NAME_DB, null, VERSION_DB);
    //this.myContext = context;
}
//Creating Table
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
{
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + COURSES_TABLE + "("
            + ID_KEYROW + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + ID_COURSE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + ID_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + ID_INSTRUCTOR + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + ID_LENGTH + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + ID_RATING + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + ID_TOPIC + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + ID_SUBJECT + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + ID_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    /* Other Method for Create DataBase.
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE courses" + "(" + ID_KEYROW + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + ID_COURSE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ID_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ID_INSTRUCTOR + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ID_LENGTH + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ID_RATING + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ID_TOPIC + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ID_SUBJECT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + ID_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
            );*/    
}       

//Updating Database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + COURSES_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}
//Insert Courses
//public void insertCourses(Integer courseid, String title, String instructor, Integer length, Integer rating, String topic, String subject, String description)
public void insertCourses()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db= this.getWritableDatabase();

    sql="INSERT INTO courses(courseid, title, instructor,  length, rating, topic, subject, description) VALUES ('1', 'Interdisciplinary Care Planning', 'Keith Savell', '60', '4.7', 'Interdisciplinary Care Planning requires members of the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to view the Care Plan as a resident centered collaborative effort - rather than as a staff centered document. Learn how to...', 'Encourage the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to work as a team and view the Care Plan as a resident-centered collaborative effort  to enhance the care and quality of resident life.', 'Interdisciplinary Care Planning requires members of the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to view the Care Plan as a resident centered collaborative effort - rather than as a staff centered document. Learn how to utilize the Care Plan to truly function as a team - working together to enhance the care and quality of resident life.')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql="INSERT INTO courses(courseid, title, instructor,  length, rating, topic, subject, description) VALUES ('2', 'Culture Change: Creating A Climate Of Care...', 'Keith Savell', '60', '5', 'Culture Change ', 'Learn to evaluate and modify the environment to support our residents with cognitive impairment as they age in place.', 'Residents with dementia and delirium are constantly assessing the environment, looking for clues to help them understand where they are, who others around them are, what they are supposed to be doing and what is expected of them.')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql="INSERT INTO courses(courseid, title, instructor,  length, rating, topic, subject, description) VALUES ('3', 'Medical Records Documentation', 'Keith Savell', '60', '5', 'Medical Records Documentation ', 'Encourage the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to work as a team and view the Care Plan as a resident-centered collaborative effort  to enhance the care and quality of resident life.', 'Interdisciplinary Care Planning requires members of the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to view the Care Plan as a resident centered collaborative effort - rather than as a staff centered document. Learn how to utilize the Care Plan to truly function as a team - working together to enhance the care and quality of resident life.')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql="INSERT INTO courses(courseid, title, instructor,  length, rating, topic, subject, description) VALUES ('4', 'Census Challenges', 'Keith Savell', '60', '4.45', 'Creative Solutions to Drive Census ', 'Learn to evaluate and modify the environment to support our residents with cognitive impairment as they age in place.', 'Residents with dementia and delirium are constantly assessing the environment, looking for clues to help them understand where they are, who others around them are, what they are supposed to be doing and what is expected of them.')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql="INSERT INTO courses(courseid, title, instructor,  length, rating, topic, subject, description) VALUES ('5', 'Fall Prevention: Reducing Fall Related Injuries', 'Keith Savell', '60', '5', 'Guidelines for Health Care Providers ', 'Encourage the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to work as a team and view the Care Plan as a resident-centered collaborative effort  to enhance the care and quality of resident life.', 'Interdisciplinary Care Planning requires members of the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to view the Care Plan as a resident centered collaborative effort - rather than as a staff centered document. Learn how to utilize the Care Plan to truly function as a team - working together to enhance the care and quality of resident life.')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql="INSERT INTO courses(courseid, title, instructor,  length, rating, topic, subject, description) VALUES ('6', 'Meaningful Engagement', 'Keith Savell', '60', '5', 'Creating The Failure Free Activity Program ', 'Learn to evaluate and modify the environment to support our residents with cognitive impairment as they age in place.', 'Residents with dementia and delirium are constantly assessing the environment, looking for clues to help them understand where they are, who others around them are, what they are supposed to be doing and what is expected of them.')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql="INSERT INTO courses(courseid, title, instructor,  length, rating, topic, subject, description) VALUES ('7', 'Dementia and Delirium', 'Keith Savell', '60', '4.69', 'The Importance of Accurate Diagnosis and Treatment ', 'Encourage the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to work as a team and view the Care Plan as a resident-centered collaborative effort  to enhance the care and quality of resident life.', 'Interdisciplinary Care Planning requires members of the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to view the Care Plan as a resident centered collaborative effort - rather than as a staff centered document. Learn how to utilize the Care Plan to truly function as a team - working together to enhance the care and quality of resident life.')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql="INSERT INTO courses(courseid, title, instructor,  length, rating, topic, subject, description) VALUES ('8', 'Delirium', 'Keith Savell', '60', '4.69', 'The Importance of Accurate Diagnosis and Treatment ', 'Encourage the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to work as a team and view the Care Plan as a resident-centered collaborative effort  to enhance the care and quality of resident life.', 'Interdisciplinary Care Planning requires members of the Interdisciplinary Treatment Team (IDT) to view the Care Plan as a resident centered collaborative effort - rather than as a staff centered document. Learn how to utilize the Care Plan to truly function as a team - working together to enhance the care and quality of resident life.')";
    db.execSQL(sql);

    //Other Style for Insert record in DB.
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); //Here from ContentValues
    values.put("courseid", "9");
    values.put("title", "xxxxxxx Care Planning");
    values.put("instructor", "Keith Savell");
    values.put("length", "60");
    values.put("rating", "4.7");
    values.put("topic", "some topic");
    values.put("subject", "some subject");
    values.put("description", "some description");
    db.insert(COURSES_TABLE, null, values);
}

public ArrayList<Courses> getCourses()
{
    db = getWritableDatabase();
    sql = "SELECT courseid, title, instructor, length, rating, topic, subject, description FROM courses";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    ArrayList<Courses> courses = new ArrayList<Courses>();


    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        Courses oCourses=new Courses();

        oCourses.courseid=cursor.getInt(0);
        oCourses.title=cursor.getString(1); //Original Value 0
        oCourses.instructor=cursor.getString(2);
        oCourses.length=cursor.getString(3);
        oCourses.rating=cursor.getString(4);
        oCourses.topic=cursor.getString(5);
        oCourses.subject=cursor.getString(6);
        oCourses.description=cursor.getString(7);
        courses.add(oCourses);          
    }       
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    return courses;     
}

public ArrayList<Courses> getItem(int position)
{
    db = getWritableDatabase();
    sql = "SELECT courseid, title, instructor, length, rating, topic, subject, description FROM courses";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    ArrayList<Courses> courses = new ArrayList<Courses>();


    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        Courses oCourses=new Courses();

        oCourses.courseid=cursor.getInt(0);
        oCourses.title=cursor.getString(1); //Original Value 0
        oCourses.instructor=cursor.getString(2);
        oCourses.length=cursor.getString(3);
        oCourses.rating=cursor.getString(4);
        oCourses.topic=cursor.getString(5);
        oCourses.subject=cursor.getString(6);
        oCourses.description=cursor.getString(7);
        courses.add(oCourses);          
    }
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    return courses;

}

public int getRowCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + COURSES_TABLE;
    SQLiteDatabase db =this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();
    //return row count.
    return rowCount;
}//GetRowCount

//Recreate database, delete all tables and create them again.
 public void resetTables(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(COURSES_TABLE, null, null);
        db.close();
    }}
```

Later in your Mainclass (or activity you want to manage the data) call methods of your DatabaseHelper.class, Hope this give you ideas...

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand SQL, relational databases, and normalization rules.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to install, name, and establish credentials (username, password, host) for your SQLite database on your server. Here is a link that relate to the Android Classes required to do this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Then you need to learn how JAVA will talk to SQL. I'm only familiar with PHP->SQL but here's a link for the JAVA->SQL connection which looks pretty similiar to PHP http://sqlzoo.net/java.htm.

SQL language is pretty straightforward.

`SELECT` is to get rows from a database table(s).

`INSERT` is to insert rows

`UPDATE` is to change values (a.k.a, fields) in rows

`DELETE` is to delete rows

Though many will probably poo-poo me for this, I got my start with SQL syntax (and connecting PHP to SQL) from: [W3CSchools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)